# Unable to extract unique words from a list using set symmetric difference

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following words in two lists

```
x = ['Director sales North America']
f = ['North America']
```

My goal is to extract only the unique elements of list x

The below code

```
x = ['Director sales North America']
f = ['North America']
res = list(set(x).symmetric_difference (set(f)))
print(res)
```

gives the output

```
['North America', 'Director sales North America']
```

ideal output required

```
['Director sales']
```

What I am missing. How can the above result be achieved?

I am ok with a regular expression solution as well. Please note the words in the lists are just example, the real goal is to extract any unique words when compared to another list.

Comment: How would this work if there were multiple strings in one or both of the lists?  `symmetric_difference` is operating on the elements of the two lists, which are the strings `North America` and `Director sales North America`.  Since neither of those strings is in both lists, both appear in the output.  If you want to split the strings, you will have to do that before calling `symmetric_difference`

Comment: Side question -- why are you using lists with one element?  It would be simpler to have true lists where each word is a separate element, or just use plain strings without any lists at all.

Comment: @JohnGordon the output from a text extraction process leaves me with 2 lists in the above format. I understand what you mean but unfortunately this is the format I have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = ['Director sales North America']
f = ['North America']
x, f = x[0].split(), f[0].split() # this line is missing!
res = list(set(x) - (set(f))) # you don't need *symmetric* difference here
print(res)
```

**Update:**
To keep the original order of words, replace fourth line of above code with:

```
res = [ word for word in x if word not in set(f) ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but using your solution, the places of the words get flipped or gets mixed up. How to preserve the place of the words. What i mean is using ur solution i get `Sales Director` but I want `Director Sales`

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. It solved the problem completely

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason to hold the strings in the list?
If yes than I would convert the strings to a list of strings where each element is the word
and than use your method:

```
x_list = x[0].split()
f_list = f[0].split()
res = list(set(x_list).symmetric_difference (set(f_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two lists, each containing a single string. Perhaps what you want is:
`x='Director sales North America'.split()`.